# navigation include loop(php switch)

Tags: php, html

I am somewhere in a loop! My browser is including over and over again my navigation until the page crashes. I dont know why. I do the switch normally in the index.php, but I want to have an intro page and therfore I want to do it in the home.php.

Here is a pic of my folder structur:

[image]

Thats my index.php:

```
<body onload="main()">
<!-- Main content -->
<div id="main">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div id="logo">
    </div><!-- End Logo -->
    <!-- h2 Webdesign & Development -->
    <h1 id="text"></h1>
    <!-- End h2 Webdesign & Development -->
    <!-- Enter link -->
    <div id="enter">
        <a href="Home" data-hover="ENTER">ENTER</a>
    </div><!-- End enter link -->
</div><!-- End main content -->
```

There is a "ENTER" Link to the real website(home.php)

Here is my navi.inc.php file:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="Home"><img data-other-src="../pics/home_button_hover.svg" src="../pics/home_button.svg" id="home" alt="Home Button"></a></li>
    <li><a href="Info">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and finally my home.php:

```
<?php
require_once    '../include/config.inc.php';

if( isset( $_GET['site'] ) ){

$site = $_GET['site'];

}else{

    $site = 'Home';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home | <?=$seiten_name?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/main.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Iceland' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/image_switch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">

    <?php

            // Navigation

            switch ( $site ) {

                case 'Home':
                    include('home.php');
                    break;

                case 'Projects':
                    include('projects.php');
                    break;

                case 'Contact':
                    include('contact.php');
                    break;

                default:
                    include('home.php');
                    break;

            }

        ?>

    <div id="preloader">
        <img src="../pics/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Preloader">
    </div>
</div>

<?php

    require('../include/navi.inc.php');

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for my poor english, but i hope you will understand my problem!! I want the home.php as my index :P

Comment: In your home.php you have an inclusion for home.php - infinity loop - Kaboom :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your home.php file you have the following code:

```
        switch ( $site ) {

            case 'Home':
                include('home.php');
                break;
```

(Same goes for your `default:` block)

Which basically means that there's a situation where the home.php file will include itself, which will cause an infinity loop.

Comment: Should be the same with the "default" in the switch right?